# PHP echo name+var

Tags: php

I basically have to create a website that display 3 random items out of a total of 10. I have named each of them $item# (# being a number 1-10) and I'm trying to display them using `echo`.

This is how I have the content stored

```
$item1 = '<img src="Images/coffee1.png" class="imgLeft" />
    <h3>Title 1</h3>
    <p>
        L.
    </p>';
```

I used this to create a variable with a random int between 1-10

```
$f1 = rand(1, 10);
```

And I'm trying to display it using this

```
<?php echo $item; ?>
```

If I put a number after item it works perfectly, but I can't figure out how to put $f1 instead.
Thank you

Comment: where you want to put `$f1`?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: @Anant I want to put $f1 after $item in the echo statement. Basically if $f1 is equal to 6, I want to echo $item6

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to declare your random number before inserting into your Item. if you do it after then your Item doesn't reconize it.
Then in php we can use a concatenation of vars like `$f1 . $f2` and it the same when we use it with String type so your Item is a String concatenated with an Integer but we want it inside the string.
In conclusion we have to concatenate String like this `

> "Your String ".$1."The rest of String"; **OR** 'Your String '.$1.'The rest of String';

`

```
$f1 = rand(1, 10);
    $item1 = '<img src="Images/coffee'. $f1 .'.png" class="imgLeft" />
          <h3>Title '. $f1 .'</h3>
          <p>L.</p>';
    <?php echo $item; ?>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

My last edited Answer Now:

It is working...

```
 $f1 = rand(1, 10);
$item = '';
$ite = $item.$f1;
$ite = '<img src="images/'.$f1.'.png" class="imgLeft" /><h3>Title '. $f1 .'</h3><p>L.</p>';

echo $ite;
```

Comment: That will only echo the random number, i've tested it a minute ago.

Comment: I tried combining $item and $f1 the way you did, but when I echo $ite, it is only echoing the random number

Comment: `$f1 = rand(1, 10);
$sample = rand(100,1000);
$item = '<h3>Title '. $f1 .'</h3><p>'.$sample.'</p>';
$ite = $item.$f1;
echo $ite;` Run this code and tell me what is your output?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I ended up solving it by using if statements

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it will work...

```
$f1 = rand(1, 10);
$$f1 = '<img src="Images/coffee'. $f1 .'.png" class="imgLeft" />
      <h3>Title '. $f1 .'</h3>
      <p>
          L.
      </p>';

echo $$f1;
```